# Magento get filterable attribute for category regardless of active filters

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I have drop down menus in the top navigation showing a list of filters.

The problem is that once a filter is added (via layered navigation), it is also removed from the drop downs.

```
$category = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($_category->getId());
$layer->setCurrentCategory($category);      
$attributes = $layer->getFilterableAttributes();
```

How can I get the filterable attributes regardless of what other filters are active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View` the filters are 'created' and we can retrieve them. With the function `getFilters()` all the layer filters are returned. For what I'm seeing in the core code, no extra logic in that function is being done to filter the active filters. So it must be the raw data.

You must change the block type of your template (where your dropdown is in) to `catalog/layer_view`.